# Joomla Form extension/component with SQL precondition to redirect page

Tags: sql, redirect, joomla, components, preconditions

I'd like to know whether there is Joomla extension/component that allows me query the back-end table;

If the result of the query is "1", show form in which user can submit and the result goes back to the back-end; and user redirected to XYZ page

If the result of the query is "0", user redirected directly to XYZ page

I've tried Fabrik component, unfortunately there is no pre-condition in the "Form"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question you are not aware of the MVC design pattern. If I put it in simple terms

Model -> Database Access

Controller -> Coordination

View -> Data Representation

You will have to read more on the above topic. Also read about how to create a custom component in Joomla.

[Developing a MVC Component/Developing a Basic Component](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component)

Comment: Thanks for your answer; @_O wow!! such a lengthy documentation; I suspect there is no way to make is simpler apart from doing the coding ourselves?

Comment: You have to code if there is not already a developed component in the Joomla extension directory.